# Invoking an elisp function and make it prompt for input

Tags: elisp

In a function that I am writing myself, I would like to invoke the command `compile` but have it run interactively, just as if I had done `Meta-x compile`. Just invoking `(compile)` doesn't work as it expects arguments. So how do force emacs to run `compile` "interactively"?

Comment: `(call-interactively compile)` is the solution - See: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html#Interactive-Call . I should have searched more before asking the question.

Comment: You should write and then accept that as an answer, rather than as a comment.

Comment: I second phils's comment - you should accept the answer (your own - that's OK AFAIK). That way, it is removed from the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
(call-interactively 'compile)
```

This does exactly what I asked for in the question.